# Acquire barrier in the double checked locking pattern

Tags: c++, multithreading

In [C++ and the Perils of Double-Checked Locking](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf), the authors give an example on how to implement the pattern correctly.

```
Singleton* Singleton::instance () {
   Singleton* tmp = pInstance;
   ... // insert memory barrier (1)
   if (tmp == 0) {
      Lock lock;
      tmp = pInstance;
      if (tmp == 0) {
         tmp = new Singleton;
         ... // insert memory barrier (2)
         pInstance = tmp;
      }
   }
   return tmp;
}
```

What I couldn't figure out, though, is if the first memory barrier must be after `Singleton* tmp = pInstance;`? (EDIT: To be clear, I understand that the barrier is needed. What I don't understand is if it must come after assigning tmp) If so why? Is the following not valid?

```
Singleton* Singleton::instance () {
   ... // insert memory barrier (1)
   if (pInstance == 0) {
      Lock lock;
      if (pInstance == 0) {
         Singleton* tmp = new Singleton;
         ... // insert memory barrier (2)
         pInstance = tmp;
      }
   }
   return pInstance;
}
```

Comment: I'm not an expert at guessing what the compiler might do, but even if it's not critical for correctness, maintaining `tmp` does avoid rereading global state more than once in the common (already initialized) case; if you're so hard up for cycles that double-checked locking seems like a good idea, avoiding repeated reads of global state makes sure you don't sacrifice some of the gains in other ways; `tmp` is stack local (so sharing isn't a concern); the compiler can safely avoid rereading it, but might not be able to optimize out a second direct read of `pInstance`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger so perhaps my modifications are valid, but the authors chose to implemented it that way for the optimizations you mentioned? Unfortunately the paper doesn't explain the reasoning for their final design other than the need for barriers.

Comment: @user1747505 Your change doesn't guarantee that a thread that sees `pInstance` as non-NULL sees the initialization of the underlying object. Which memory barrier do you think ensures that, considering that a thread that sees `pInstance` as non-NULL never goes through any memory barriers.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Good explanation, thanks. So, given what you said (you can correct me if I'm wrong here), it seems fine to move memory barrier 1 down to be just above the final return, but it cannot be moved up to be the first line in the function. My second code example would be valid if the barrier was immediately before the return statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is essential. Otherwise, reads that occur after the `if` may be prefetched by the CPU before the copy, which would be a disaster. In the case where `pInstance` is not NULL and we don't acquire any locks, you must guarantee that reads that occur after the read of `pInstance` in the code are not re-ordered to before the read of `pInstance`.

Consider:

```
Singleton* tmp = pInstance;
if (tmp == 0) { ... }
return tmp->foo;
```

What happens if the CPU reads `tmp->foo` before `tmp`? For example, the CPU could optimize this to:

```
bool loaded = false;
int return_value = 0;

if (pInstance != NULL)
{ // do the fetch early
     return_value = pInstance->foo;
     loaded = true;
}

Singleton* tmp = pInstance;
if (tmp == 0) { ... }

return loaded ? return_value : tmp->foo;
```

Notice what this does? The read of `tmp->foo` has now moved to before the check if the pointer is non-NULL. This is a perfectly legal memory prefetch optimization (speculative read) that a CPU might do. But it's absolutely disastrous to the logic of double checked locking.

It is absolutely vital that code after the `if (tmp == 0)` not prefetch anything from before we see `pInstance` as non-NULL. So you need something to prevent the CPU from reorganizing the code's memory operations as above. A memory barrier does this.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't the assignment to `pInstance` within the `if` constitute a sequence point that prevents such a premature read? Not sequencing would make this broken even in the single-threaded case.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Sequence points are a single-threaded concept. They are totally inapplicable to synchronization across threads which involves the order in which memory operations take place. Do you agree that without a memory barrier, the optimization I describe above is a valid prefetch?

Comment: No, that's exactly my point. Fetching `tmp->foo` would be invalid in any scenario where the contents of the `if` block could reassign `tmp`, because actually dereferencing `NULL` would be invalid; a compiler/processor that did this would segfault even in a 100% single-threaded scenario. (Note: Some processors have a concept of speculative prefetch that doesn't require a valid address, GCC exposes this with stuff like `__builtin_prefetch`, but that's a different case, since it's functionally a noop when the prefetch is of invalid memory or if you later read a different address).

Comment: @ShadowRanger -- I think the issue is not that `pInstance->foo` is read from the wrong location, but that without memory barrier #1, it's possible that this CPU has a stale copy of the cache line containing `pInstance->foo`.  The writes that were flushed by memory barrier #2 have been commited to main memory before the `pInstance` update, but the reader may use stale values instead of rereading main memory, since it didn't have a barrier.

Comment: @BenVoigt: But there is still a barrier in the OP's example, it just precedes the `if` check. Both barriers are intact, it's just that the read and test of `pInstance` in the OP's code follows the barrier, rather than having the read (to stack variable) precede it, and the test follow it. So assuming reads/writes of the `pInstance` pointer itself are atomic (which the paper assumes), then pInstance is either the fully initialized object copied from the innermost `tmp` assignment, or not assigned at all, right?

Comment: @ShadowRanger: While I admit I don't know any way on real processors that the cache line could get loaded between memory barrier #1 and the code that uses `pInstance` and `pInstance->foo`, the fact remains that the entire initialization and memory barrier #2 and publication could take place on a second core, all after the first core performs the memory barrier #1.  Then memory barrier #1 would have no interaction with the update of `pInstance->foo`.  I guess a speculative read of another variable that happens to share a cache line could populate the cache with stale data.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Hmm... that sounds plausible. The read would precede the memory barrier because it's already assumed that pointer read/write is atomic; if the actual assignment has occurred, thanks to the barrier on write, the contents of `pInstance` must have been flushed to main memory. We read the pointer atomically, then barrier, to ensure that the local cache of the contents pointed to is refreshed from main memory. Okay, that makes sense.

Comment: The failure case without separating the read from the test would then be: 1: CPU1 enters getter, locks, initializes new instance, doesn't yet assign to `pInstance`. 2: CPU2 enters, barriers, and (who knows why) populates local CPU cache with data including data at the address `pInstance` is about to point to which hasn't been flushed to by CPU1 yet. 3. CPU1 flushes data (too late), then atomically writes `pInstance` 4. CPU2 atomically reads `pInstance`, says "we're good", and returns it. 5. Caller on CPU2 accesses value, gets cached copy (because no barrier followed read of `pInstance`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger The fault would be speculative and would never get executed. In the case where the pointer is NULL, the read doesn't occur. So neither does the fault. (When a CPU does a speculative read, it stores the result and uses it only if the read actually occurs.) The barrier before the `if` does nothing because it is before the read of `pInstance`, too early to close the window between reading `pInstance` and reading things it points to.

Comment: Great information. The only real CPU where this would happen is probably DEC alpha(end of life). On x86 and ARM CPU's as of today, memory barrier #2, does not only ensure that the stores before the barrier are sent out to the bus before the stores after the barrier, but it also ensures that these stores are "observed" by other CPUs in the same order, ie if pInstance points to a valid address, then contents pointed to pInstance will also be the latest contents.

Comment: Given such guarantees, memory barrier #1 really only needs to be a compiler barrier, to prevent reordering of instructions past the if statement. However, without memory barrier #1, you are not writing portable code

Answer (score 1):

Why are you still talking about the paper from 2004? C++ 11 guarantees static variables are initialized only once. Here is your fullly-working, 100% correct singleton (which, of course, is an anti-pattern on it's own):

```
static TheTon& TheTon::instance() {
    static TheTon ton;
    return ton;
}
```

Comment: This is a good point to bring up so that people with similar questions to mine know of potentially better alternatives to the design. My question, though, came from general curiosity. Also, pre-C++11 compilers are still very much in use in the industry for various reasons and there is a lot of legacy code out there that must be maintained.