# Double check locking pattern issue in C

Tags: c, memory-barriers

As everybody who has looked into this, I've read the paper http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf

I have a question about the barriers when DCLP is implemented on a C structure. Here is the code:

```
typedef struct _singleton_object {
    int x;
    int y;
} sobject;

static sobject *singleton_object = NULL;

sobject *get_singleton_instance()
{
    sobject *tmp = singleton_object;

    /* Insert barrier here - compiler or cpu specific or both? */
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        mutex_lock(&lock); /* assume lock is declared and initialized properly*/
        tmp = singleton_object;
        if (tmp == NULL) {
            tmp = (sobject *)malloc(sizeof(sobject)); /* assume malloc succeeds */
            tmp->x = 5;
            tmp->y = 7;

            /* Insert barrier here - compiler or cpu specific or both ?*/
            singleton_object = tmp;
        }
        mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

The first question is as in the comments: When the paper describes insert barriers does it mean just the compiler, CPU or both? I assume both.

My second question is: what prevents the compiler from replacing tmp with singleton_object in the code? What forces the load of singleton_object into tmp, which could be in a register or stack in compiler generated code ? what if the compiler, at every reference to tmp, actually does a load into register from &singleton_object and discard that value?
It seems like the solution in the paper referenced below depends on the fact that we are using the local variable. if the compiler does not load the value in the pointer variable to the local variable tmp, we are back to the original problem described in the paper.

My third question is: Assuming, the compiler does copy the value of singleton_object locally into a register or stack(i.e. variable tmp), Why do we need the first barrier? There should be no reordering of tmp = singleton_object and if (tmp == NULL) in the beginning of the function, since there is an implicit read after write dependency with tmp. Also, even if we read a stale value from the CPU's cache in the first load to tmp, it should be read as NULL. If it is not NULL, then the object construction should be complete, since the thread/CPU that constructs it should execute the barrier, which ensures that the stores to x and y are visible to all CPU's before singleton_object has a non NULL value.

Comment: Note: Names starting with `_` are reserved for the implementation for all namespaces at file-scope. Also the paper is a bit outdated. It also is about C++, not C, which are different languages. Not clear what you try to accomplish (a [mcve] might help), but C11 (and C++11 coincidentally) introduced atomic types and functions, you might want to have a look at if you need some kind of barriers, etc.

Comment: Paper is out dated but very relevant to both c and c++. I'm writing c code. I cannot use c++ in my environment so looking into c11 won't help anything. Also, I Don't care about the _. This is example code and a conceptual question. What I'm trying to achieve is to have a singleton object in c code, that works on a multi core CPU.

Comment: "I cannot use c++ in my environment so looking into c11 won't help anything" - **C11 is not C++!** And how is that related to paper (which is not really outdated, considering the use of computers has not reduced paper production, but massively increased actually). The Underscore **is** relevant, as your `struct` can collide with declarations of your header files. But as you apparently don't want well meant advice, I wish you luck with whatever you are trying. (Btw: the concept of singletons does not make any sense in C either, as there are no objects in the OOP sense).

Comment: @olaf, apologies. I misread C11 as C++11, since I was looking into atomics in C++11 at the time of your comment. Point taken on the _. Definitely relevant outside the scope of this discussion. Anyway not to pick up an argument, why would you say singleton don't make sense in C? Objects are  not concepts of object oriented programming languages only. It is a general concept. If you have written any code in the linux kernel, you will see tons of examples of objects and design patterns, all written in C.

Comment: The term "singleton" does not make any sense if you don't have bound functions! And no, "object" is not a general concept. C **does have** objects. But they are very different from the OOP "objects". And Singleton only makes sense if you have OOP - that's what I actually wrote. Note you should differentiate abstraction layers; this is about C, so we should use C context, not OOP context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > When the paper describes insert barriers does it mean just the compiler, CPU or both?

   Both barriers should be *CPU-barriers* (which implies *compiler barriers*).
2. > what prevents the compiler from replacing `tmp` with `singleton_object` in the code?

   The barrier after assignment

   ```
   sobject *tmp = singleton_object;
   ```

   among other things means (both for CPU and compiler):

   ** All **read** accesses issued before the barrier should be **completed before the barrier**.

   Because of that, compiler is *not allowed to read* `singleton_object` variable *instead* of `tmp` after the barrier.
3. > If it (`singleton_object`) is not NULL, then the object construction should be complete, since the thread/CPU that constructs it should execute the barrier, which ensures that the stores to `x` and `y` are visible to all CPU's before `singleton_object` has a non NULL value.

   You need to perform barrier for *actual use* these "visible" variables `x` and `y`. Without the barrier read thread may use *stale* values.

   As a rule, every syncrhonization between different threads requires some sort of "barrier" on **both sides**: read and write.

Comment: Tsyvarev, thanks. follow up questions: You said that the barrier after the assignment (sobject *tmp = singleton_object) is what prevents the compiler from reading singleton_object. What if I have a couple of assignments to local variables after (sobject *tmp = singleton_object)? suppose I have sobject *tmp2 = singleton_object2 and sobject *tpm3 = singleton_object3. Does the barrier prevent all the tmp* variables from being replaced ? Does that mean, if a function has a barrier, no local variables can be replaced or optimized ?

Comment: Also if I don't have the first barrier, is it then legal for the compiler to optimize the use of the local variable and directly refer to the global variable ?

Comment: Replacement of variables means that compiler is **allowed to reorder read** from *global* variable to the point where *local* variable is **used**. If first operation is issued *before* the barrier, and the second - *after* it, then compiler cannot do that. Otherwise it can. Does this help to undestand your followed questions?

Comment: Thanks Tsyvarev. I think I understand. Let me know if this is a good way to rephrase: The barrier, during compile time, disallows the compiler from making any optimizations across the barrier boundary, so the load into the local variable MUST be present and the compiler cannot remove the load because its effects are present before and after the barrier. From the CPU perspective you are essentially requesting the cache state to be updated to the latest possible value of tmp, before reading the value at memory location tmp? what would happen if tmp is in a register ?

Comment: The statement about compiler is true. As for CPU, it is unrelated whether `tmp` is a memory cell or a register: it contains value of `singleton_object` which has been read before the barrier. The barrier enforce CPU to clear its cache, so when you access fields of singleton object, you get their *actual* values, which has been initialized by the writer thread (remain your original question about that).

Comment: Thanks tsyvarev. With your explanation and the one from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33115687/acquire-barrier-in-the-double-checked-locking-pattern, I think clears it. The first barrier, forces the CPU to clear/update its cache, so that when the thread/cpu that read tmp as a non NULL value, has the updated values of x and y. That correct ?

Comment: Yes, when value of `tmp` is not NULL, this means that value of `singleton_object` is not NULL too, so writer thread has published it work into memory. As for read barrier, it forces read thread to read that memory instead of possibly cached values.

Comment: After reading some more on the CPU specific barriers, the first barrier can be a compiler barrier only. We don't need CPU barrier on most of todays architectures(atleast x86 and ARMv8) since the execution of the second barrier guarantees that no CPU will see the new pointer value but old data for the fields. Of course, this is not portable and only applicable if you are writing architecture specific code.